# RPM + writing script in the spec file

Tags: linux

is it possible to write ksh script in the spec file?

the target is after I perform rpm -i my_rpm.rpm

according to the spec file , ksh script will do some installation & configuration

for example run other script and edit some files

THX

Answer (score 0):

The `-p` argument to the various script section headers will allow you to specify an alternate interpreter.